# CMake target dependency to compile protobuf files

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I want to build a c++ static lib out of some `protobuf` definitions with `cmake/make`.
I made a custom `COMMAND` to compile the `protobuf` to `c++`, and I set it as a `PRE_BUILD` dependency to my static lib.

```
project(mylib)

set(PROTO_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto_definitions")

file(GLOB PROTO_FILES "${PROTO_PATH}/*.proto")
foreach(PROTO_FILE in ${PROTO_FILES})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "[.]proto$" ".pb.cc" OUTPUT_SOURCE ${PROTO_FILE})
    list(APPEND OUTPUT_SOURCES ${OUTPUT_SOURCE}) 
endforeach()

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
                   PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND protoc --cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compiled_proto ${PROTO_FILES}
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   COMMENT "some comment")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${OUTPUT_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

I get the following error when running cmake:
*CMake Error: cannot determine link language for target "mylib"*

Regardless of this error, the makefiles are generated, but when I make mylib, it does not trigger any proto compilation

Comment: Please mind your language when posting.

Comment: Yeah, I spot it and was editing it, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach more native to CMake would be to add custom commands with the `OUTPUT` signature to generate the `.cc` files, and then use them as sources for the library normally. That way, they CMake will know what they are and how to produce them:

```
project(mylib)

set(PROTO_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto_definitions")

file(GLOB PROTO_FILES "${PROTO_PATH}/*.proto")
foreach(PROTO_FILE in ${PROTO_FILES})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "[.]proto$" ".pb.cc" OUTPUT_SOURCE ${PROTO_FILE})
    list(APPEND OUTPUT_SOURCES ${OUTPUT_SOURCE}) 
endforeach()

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_SOURCES}
                   COMMAND protoc --cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compiled_proto ${PROTO_FILES}
                   DEPENDS ${PROTO_FILES}
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   COMMENT "some comment")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${OUTPUT_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Done this way, there will be one command which reads all the `.proto` files and produces all the `.cc` files — which means that if any of the `.proto` file changes, all the `.cc` files will be re-generated. I am not familiar with Protobuffers so I cannot know whether that's sane or not. If they are independent, it would be better to introduce one `add_custom_command` for each output file.

Also, given the arguments you're passing to `protocc`, you might have to modify the paths in `OUTPUT_SOURCES` to correctly point to the generated files.

Also note that CMake comes with a [FindProtobuf](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html) module which defines a `protobuf_generate_cpp()` command, so you might want to use that instead of hand-coding the Protobuf support.

Comment: This is what I first tried, but the custom command is not invoked as dependency to `mylib` and when I run `make mylib`, it just fails as it cannot find any of the source files.

Comment: I wanted to use FindProtobuf, but I don;t have it available on the build machine.

Comment: @hdoradu Are the paths in `OUTPUT_SOURCES` actually correct? It seems to me that maybe they're pointing into `PROTO_PATH`, but the files are produces in `compiled_proto`.

Comment: @hdoradu `FindProtobuf` has been in CMake since at least 2.8.0 (which is positively *ancient*), are you *sure* it's not available?

Comment: I am restricted to using cmake 2.6 for now. The `OUTPUT_SOURCES` is indeed different then `protoc` output path, but this does not change the fact that the `.proto` files are not compiled anywhere. I updated the output path to be the same as `OUTPUT_SOURCES`, but it's the same. `protoc` is not invoked.

Comment: @hdoradu That's *weird.* And weirder is the fact that CMake is not complaining about the library's sources missing. Is it possible that there are some files somewhere which match what's in `OUTPUT_SOURCES` and are new enough to confuse a dependency scanner? Also, I noticed you're generating the `.cc` files into a *source* directory, which is strange. I would expect these to go into the *binary* directory (and of course `OUTPUT_SOURCES` to refer to them there).

Comment: Yes, I changed the `.cc` path just to be the same for a test, this was not the issue. I had problems with protoc path. This version works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Comment for the answer above: There is no `in` in cmake foreach, which spend me some time to solve it.

After studying his answer(very thanks!), I summarized a method that works for me, which has the following characteristics:

1. Proto dir and Output dir can be different
2. Generate grpc_output
3. Create a custom_command for each proto

My project strcuture is:

- hwpb/ (a library for super project)

  - cpp/

    - hwpb/ (store *.pb.cc, *.pb.h)
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - proto/ (store protos)
  - go/ (and other languages, not mentioned here)

And this is my CMakeListx.txt:

```
set(PROTO_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../proto")
set(OUTPUT_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hwpb")

file(GLOB PROTO_FILES "${PROTO_DIR}/*.proto")
foreach(PROTO_FILE ${PROTO_FILES})
    get_filename_component (FILENAME ${PROTO_FILE} NAME_WLE)
    set(PROTO_SRC "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.pb.cc")
    set(PROTO_HDR "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.pb.h")
    set(GRPC_SRC "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.grpc.pb.cc")
    set(GRPC_HDR "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.grpc.pb.h")

    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${PROTO_SRC}" "${PROTO_HDR}" "${GRPC_SRC}" "${GRPC_HDR}"
        COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
        ARGS --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}
            --cpp_out="${OUTPUT_DIR}" --grpc_out="${OUTPUT_DIR}"
            -I"${PROTO_DIR}" "${PROTO_FILE}"
        DEPENDS ${PROTO_FILE}
    )
    list(APPEND OUTPUT_SOURCES ${PROTO_SRC} ${GRPC_HDR})
endforeach()

add_library(hwpb ${OUTPUT_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(hwpb ${_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE} ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})
target_include_directories(hwpb PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```